# Direct showing of image in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Is there a function which gets path and image name as parameter and shows a picture as a return?

I've got this line of code and I need to change it to show picture instead of downloading it:

```
return response()->download($upload->getFilePath($var->image, 'var', $var->id), $var->image['name']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to show it instead of downloading.. you should only return the construct the url of the image stored in your public file. Something like this:

```
return asset($the_route_to_your_file . $the_name_of_your_file);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the **storage_path()** method.

usage :

```
$path = storage_path('app/file.txt');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-storage-path

Answer (score 0):

You should give public "storage" URL(image, pdf etc..) but if that file is granted for some users so you should return this:

```
return response()->file(FILE_PATH);
```